# git add --patch yields "Not a git repository"

Tags: git, version-control, workflow

I'm currently on a Windows 7x64 box developing some software using Git for version control.

I'm quite used to doing `git add -p` so that I don't have to worry about working on one feature at a time. Lately, though, the feature has not been working for me. When I run it, I get this:

```
PS C:\Users\path\to\folder> git add -p .
fatal: Not a git repository: '.git'
rev-parse --show-prefix: command returned error: 128
```

The same breaks for `git reset -p`, but not `git add` and `git reset` for some reason. All other functionality for the repository works normally. I've already tried reinitializing, deleting my working directory and recloning the repo from Github, and  `git checkout -f` as suggested in one article.

Why am I going through this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: sounds like something special in the `-p` code path. It's not that hard to browse the codebase on github to see where the error message may be coming from and which condition is failing (hence the error in your repo?)

Comment: it also fails the same way when I try patch adding any file in the repo, not just the whole directory.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me when I installed GitHub for Windows over msysgit. I finally realized that the version of git I was using with my normal shell (Console2) was older than the version  used by GitHub Shell. The Console2 version had this issue, while GitHub Shell worked perfectly.

I uninstalled the old version of git, and added the following line to my `profile.ps1`

```
.(Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1")
```

This loads the powershell script that GitHub for Windows generates on install and will properly source the latest version of git.